# Revoking a certificate from ActiveMQ's truststore doesn't work

Tags: java, ssl, activemq-classic, tls1.2, keytool

I have an instance of Apache ActiveMQ  5.16.3 with Java 8 in a Debian Docker container (Kubernetes).

It's configured to use mutual SSL in `/opt/activemq/conf/activemq.xml`:

```xml
        <sslContext>
            <sslContext 
                keyStore="/etc/data/my-bridge-broker.ks"
                keyStorePassword="my-pass" 
                trustStore="/etc/data/broker_to_client.ts"
                trustStorePassword="my-pass"
             />
        </sslContext>
        <!--- ... --->
        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61714?transport.enabledProtocols=TLSv1.2&amp;transport.needClientAuth=true"/>
        </transportConnectors>
```

The mutual SSL works properly, and I am able to connect from a sample Java client, using [ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory](https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory.html) providing the appropriate certificates in the truststore and keystore and passwords.

Next, while the broker was running I removed the client's certificate by its alias from the server's trust store:

```
cd /etc/data
keytool -delete -alias <client-cert-name> -keystore broker_to_client.ts -storepass my-pass
```

Surprisingly, the client is still able to connect. I restarted the server and the client can still connect and post messages on the queues. Any idea why? I thought the truststore defines which client certificates will be allowed?

Looking at the [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl) they recommend using Certificate Revocation List (CRL) or Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP). They don't mention the option to remove from the truststore. Does this mean ActiveMQ doesn't use the truststore file?

Comment: Did you do this while the broker is running or did you stop the broker, delete the client's cert from the truststore, and then restart the broker?

Comment: @JustinBertram I did it while the broker was running.

Comment: Are both the client and broker certificates self-signed or are they signed by a trusted authority?

Comment: Can you provide the commands you used to generate the keystores and truststores for the client & broker?

Comment: @JustinBertram They're from a trusted authority, which is installed into the Kubernetes cluster

Comment: @JustinBertram below are the commands we use to generate the client certs:


> keytool -import -alias {{alias}} -keystore broker_to_client.ts -file client.crt -deststorepass {{password}}


> keytool -import -alias amq-artemis-broker-ca -keystore broker_to_client.ts -file ca.crt -deststorepass {{ password }} (edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the client's certificate is issued from a trusted authority then it doesn't matter if the it's in the broker's truststore. The client's certificate will still be trusted because it's from a *trusted* authority. The broker's truststore is only there to include certificates that come from an untrusted authority or are self-signed.

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm the client certificate works and it can connect even if it's not added to the trust store at all.